# wxpython: buttons in ButtonPanel changes to previously chosen button

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have a BoxSizer(horizontal) inside which there are two ButtonPanels (say bp1 and bp2) each containing buttons (initially bp2 is empty). Depending on the button chosen from bp1 the buttons in bp2 should change.
Let,
For button1 (in bp1)->corresponding buttons in bp2 are a and b.
For button2 (in bp1)->corresponding buttons in bp2 are c, d.

[click to See my user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARIf2.png) .

My problem is that:

When i choose button1 from bp1, the correct buttons appears in bp2( ie, a and b), when i choose button 2 from bp1 then also correct button appears (ie, c and d) in place of previous one , but as soon as i take mouse over the produced button in bp2, the button (of bp2) get changes to the buttons a and b.

Can any one suggest me what is the problem?

Below is my code:

```
def do_OnRecog(self, event):

    self.vSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.work_panel.SetSizer(self.vSizer1)

    self.buttonMenu1 = bp.ButtonPanel(self.work_panel, -1)
    self.buttonMenu1_2= bp.ButtonPanel(self.work_panel, -1)

    self.face = bp.ButtonInfo(self.buttonMenu1, wx.NewId(), wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pathExe), "images/face_recog.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), shortHelp = "face recoginition")
    self.buttonMenu1.AddButton(self.face)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event:OnFaceButton(event, self), self.face) 

    self.buttonMenu1.AddSeparator()

    self.char = bp.ButtonInfo(self.buttonMenu1, wx.NewId(), wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pathExe), "images/char_recog.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), shortHelp = "character recognition")
    self.buttonMenu1.AddButton(self.char)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event:OnCharButton(event, self), self.char)

    self.vSizer1.Add(self.buttonMenu1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.vSizer1.Add((130,130))
    self.vSizer1.Add(self.buttonMenu1_2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

# Doing layout
    self.buttonMenu1.DoLayout()
    self.buttonMenu1_2.DoLayout()
    self.vSizer1.Layout()
    self.Layout()


def OnFaceButton(event,self):

    self.vSizer1.Detach(self.buttonMenu1_2)
    self.vSizer1.Remove(self.buttonMenu1_2)

    self.buttonMenu1_2= bp.ButtonPanel(self.work_panel, -1)

    self.camera_icon = bp.ButtonInfo(self.buttonMenu1_2, wx.NewId(), wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pathExe), "images/camera_icon.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), text="Open Camera" ,shortHelp = "open camera")
    self.buttonMenu1_2.AddButton(self.camera_icon)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, FaceRec_From_Camera, self.camera_icon)

    self.buttonMenu1_2.AddSeparator()
    self.folder_icon = bp.ButtonInfo(self.buttonMenu1_2, wx.NewId(), wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pathExe), "images/folder_icon.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), text="Open Folder" ,shortHelp = "open folder")
    self.buttonMenu1_2.AddButton(self.folder_icon)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, FaceRec_From_File, self.folder_icon)


    self.vSizer1.Add(self.buttonMenu1_2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

     # Doing layout
    self.buttonMenu1_2.DoLayout()
    self.vSizer1.Layout()
    self.Layout()     





def OnCharButton(event,self):

    self.vSizer1.Detach(self.buttonMenu1_2)
    self.vSizer1.Remove(self.buttonMenu1_2)

    self.buttonMenu1_2= bp.ButtonPanel(self.work_panel, -1)

    self.image_icon = bp.ButtonInfo(self.buttonMenu1_2, wx.NewId(), wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pathExe), "images/image_icon.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), text="Open file" ,shortHelp = "choose image")
    self.buttonMenu1_2.AddButton(self.image_icon)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, OCR_From_Image, self.image_icon)

    self.buttonMenu1_2.AddSeparator()

    self.web_icon = bp.ButtonInfo(self.buttonMenu1_2, wx.NewId(), wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(pathExe), "images/web_icon.png"), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), text="Open from web" ,shortHelp = "open image from web")
    self.buttonMenu1_2.AddButton(self.web_icon)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, OCR_From_Web, self.web_icon)

    self.vSizer1.Add(self.buttonMenu1_2, 0, wx.EXPAND)

# Doing layout
    self.buttonMenu1_2.DoLayout()
    self.vSizer1.Layout()
    self.Layout()
```

Comment: Sounds like you are binding an EVT_MOTION or EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS somewhere

Comment: NO, I am only using EVT_BUTTON event to link the buttons in the buttonPanel .

Comment: As you haven't posted a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, we can't test it for you (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)